# PHP preg_match for url

Tags: php, preg-match

```
$request = '/test.php?action=save&key=e7s2uHhKKtcM32cHKUKM&login=test';
$param = preg_match("#^test.php?action=save&key=(\w+)&login=(\w+)($)#", $request, $match);
print_r($param);
```

It's not working. How to fix?

Comment: The `^` matches the start of string (and you have `/` in the input as the first char), and `?` must be escaped. See [this PHP demo](https://ideone.com/Zn5CQa).

Comment: It would help any reader if you tell us what the result of `print_r($param);` is in your question. It gives slightly more information than just stating "It's not working".

Comment: There are better ways to parse a url, take a look at `parse_url()` and `parse_str()`.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware Result = 0

Comment: @jeroen dynamic parameters must be

Comment: So be they must...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1. You need to escape your preg control characters "`.`" and "`?`"
2. You are matching `^test` meaning the string should start with "`test`", while your string starts with "`/test`"
3. I highly recommend to use single ticks so you don't have to escape your escape characters "`\`".

   ```
   $param = preg_match('#^/test\.php\?action=save&key=(\w+)&login=(\w+)($)#', $request, $match);
   print_r($param); // 1
   print_r($match); // Array (
   // (
   //     [0] => /test.php?action=save&key=e7s2uHhKKtcM32cHKUKM&login=test
   //     [1] => e7s2uHhKKtcM32cHKUKM
   //     [2] => test
   //     [3] => 
   // )
   ```

Comment: Thanks. It is working for me :-)